# ¿Cómo arreglo el siguiente error con style?

Tags: html

En si no es un error, es una línea mal escrita pero no sé cuál es, esto tiene que ver con html. Yo pongo

```
<style>
        header {
            background: black 
        }

        footer {
            background: green 
        }
</style>
```

pero me sale un texto y no me cambia el color del header y del footer, solo me agrega un texto.

Comment: Prueba con la propiedad completa que es `background-color`

Comment: ok lo hare gracias

Comment: emm no sigue igual, lo que pasa es que la etiqueta style esta mal, pero nose porque

Comment: Si no agregas tu código completo poco podemos hacer, edita y agrégalo

Comment: tienes facebook?

Comment: La ayuda es aquí, te recomiendo leas el [tour] y veas [ask]

Comment: ah gracias igual

Comment: Santi, serias tan amable de poner el codigo entero? no pongas solo el style porfa

Comment: @LearningDeveloper en realidad no, no es necesario porque es la última declaración antes de cerrar la regla con la llave.

Answer (score 0):

El codigo **CSS** tiene que estar en un bloque `<style>` o en un fichero refereciado en la cabecera.

Por lo que comentas, te falta escribir el bloque `<style>`

Te quedaria asi:

```
<style>

    header { 
        background: black; 
    }
 
    footer { 
        background: green; 
   }

</style>
```